# Android studio error cannot find path specified

Tags: android

I have added a login activity into android studio and installed google play services but when i run the program i keep getting the following error. I thought it was due to 64 method issue with merging multiple dix files but the solution to that did not work. anyone any ideas?? thanks

```
Executing tasks: [:app:assembleDebug]

Parallel execution with configuration on demand is an incubating feature.
Relying on packaging to define the extension of the main artifact has been deprecated and is scheduled to be removed in Gradle 2.0
:app:preBuild
:app:compileDebugNdk
:app:preDebugBuild
:app:checkDebugManifest
:app:preReleaseBuild
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportAppcompatV71910Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServices4452Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareDebugDependencies
:app:compileDebugAidl UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:app:mergeDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:mergeDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:processDebugManifest UP-TO-DATE
:app:processDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugSources UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugJava
:app:dexDebug
unknown output extension: E:\year4\4thYearProject\projectCode\Train
usage:
  dx --dex [--debug] [--verbose] [--positions=<style>] [--no-locals]
  [--no-optimize] [--statistics] [--[no-]optimize-list=<file>] [--no-strict]
  [--keep-classes] [--output=<file>] [--dump-to=<file>] [--dump-width=<n>]
  [--dump-method=<name>[*]] [--verbose-dump] [--no-files] [--core-library]
  [--num-threads=<n>] [--incremental] [--force-jumbo]
  [--multi-dex [--main-dex-list=<file> [--minimal-main-dex]]
  [<file>.class | <file>.{zip,jar,apk} | <directory>] ...
    Convert a set of classfiles into a dex file, optionally embedded in a
    jar/zip. Output name must end with one of: .dex .jar .zip .apk or be a directory.
    Positions options: none, important, lines.
    --multi-dex: allows to generate several dex files if needed. This option is 
    exclusive with --incremental, causes --num-threads to be ignored and only
    supports folder or archive output.
    --main-dex-list=<file>: <file> is a list of class file names, classes defined by
    those class files are put in classes.dex.
    --minimal-main-dex: only classes selected by --main-dex-list are to be put in
    the main dex.
  dx --annotool --annotation=<class> [--element=<element types>]
  [--print=<print types>]
  dx --dump [--debug] [--strict] [--bytes] [--optimize]
  [--basic-blocks | --rop-blocks | --ssa-blocks | --dot] [--ssa-step=<step>]
  [--width=<n>] [<file>.class | <file>.txt] ...
    Dump classfiles, or transformations thereof, in a human-oriented format.
  dx --find-usages <file.dex> <declaring type> <member>
    Find references and declarations to a field or method.
    declaring type: a class name in internal form, like Ljava/lang/Object;
    member: a field or method name, like hashCode
  dx -J<option> ... <arguments, in one of the above forms>
    Pass VM-specific options to the virtual machine that runs dx.
  dx --version
    Print the version of this tool (1.8).
  dx --help
    Print this message.
The system cannot find the path specified.
The system cannot find the path specified.
The system cannot find the path specified.
The system cannot find the path specified.
The system cannot find the path specified.

 FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:dexDebug'.
> com.android.ide.common.internal.LoggedErrorException: Failed to run command:
    C:\Users\carl\AppData\Local\Android\android-studio\sdk\build-tools\19.1.0\dx.bat --dex --num-threads=4 --multi-dex --output E:\year4\4thYearProject\projectCode\Train&Gain\app\build\intermediates\dex\debug E:\year4\4thYearProject\projectCode\Train&Gain\app\build\intermediates\classes\debug E:\year4\4thYearProject\projectCode\Train&Gain\app\build\intermediates\dependency-cache\debug E:\year4\4thYearProject\projectCode\Train&Gain\app\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\com.google.android.gms\play-services\4.4.52\classes.jar C:\Users\carl\AppData\Local\Android\android-studio\sdk\extras\android\m2repository\com\android\support\support-v4\19.1.0\support-v4-19.1.0.jar E:\year4\4thYearProject\projectCode\Train&Gain\app\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\com.android.support\appcompat-v7\19.1.0\classes.jar
Error Code:
    1
Output:
    unknown output extension: E:\year4\4thYearProject\projectCode\Train
    usage:
      dx --dex [--debug] [--verbose] [--positions=<style>] [--no-locals]
      [--no-optimize] [--statistics] [--[no-]optimize-list=<file>] [--no-strict]
      [--keep-classes] [--output=<file>] [--dump-to=<file>] [--dump-width=<n>]
      [--dump-method=<name>[*]] [--verbose-dump] [--no-files] [--core-library]
      [--num-threads=<n>] [--incremental] [--force-jumbo]
      [--multi-dex [--main-dex-list=<file> [--minimal-main-dex]]
      [<file>.class | <file>.{zip,jar,apk} | <directory>] ...
        Convert a set of classfiles into a dex file, optionally embedded in a
        jar/zip. Output name must end with one of: .dex .jar .zip .apk or be a directory.
        Positions options: none, important, lines.
        --multi-dex: allows to generate several dex files if needed. This option is 
        exclusive with --incremental, causes --num-threads to be ignored and only
        supports folder or archive output.
        --main-dex-list=<file>: <file> is a list of class file names, classes defined by
        those class files are put in classes.dex.
        --minimal-main-dex: only classes selected by --main-dex-list are to be put in
        the main dex.
      dx --annotool --annotation=<class> [--element=<element types>]
      [--print=<print types>]
      dx --dump [--debug] [--strict] [--bytes] [--optimize]
      [--basic-blocks | --rop-blocks | --ssa-blocks | --dot] [--ssa-step=<step>]
      [--width=<n>] [<file>.class | <file>.txt] ...
        Dump classfiles, or transformations thereof, in a human-oriented format.
      dx --find-usages <file.dex> <declaring type> <member>
        Find references and declarations to a field or method.
        declaring type: a class name in internal form, like Ljava/lang/Object;
        member: a field or method name, like hashCode
      dx -J<option> ... <arguments, in one of the above forms>
        Pass VM-specific options to the virtual machine that runs dx.
      dx --version
        Print the version of this tool (1.8).
      dx --help
        Print this message.
    The system cannot find the path specified.
    The system cannot find the path specified.
    The system cannot find the path specified.
    The system cannot find the path specified.
    The system cannot find the path specified.


* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 1 mins 44.126 secs
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Tip: Check the output and try to understand what went wrong before posting it here.*

Look what the error says:

> unknown output extension: E:\year4\4thYearProject\projectCode\Train

And then look once again on the dx command's output parameter:

> C:\Users\carl\AppData\Local\Android\android-studio\sdk\build-tools\19.1.0\dx.bat
>   --dex --num-threads=4 --multi-dex **--output E:\year4\4thYearProject\projectCode\Train&Gain\app\build\intermediates\dex\debug
>   E:\year4\4thYearProject\projectCode\Train&Gain\app\build\intermediates\classes\debug
>   E:\year4\4thYearProject\projectCode\Train&Gain\app\build\intermediates\dependency-cache\debug
>   E:\year4\4thYearProject\projectCode\Train&Gain\app\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\com.google.android.gms\play-services\4.4.52\classes.jar
>   C:\Users\carl\AppData\Local\Android\android-studio\sdk\extras\android\m2repository\com\android\support\support-v4\19.1.0\support-v4-19.1.0.jar
>   E:\year4\4thYearProject\projectCode\Train&Gain\app\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\com.android.support\appcompat-v7\19.1.0\classes.jar**

Can you see the [possible] error now? It looks like the dx command terminates at '&' sign. Remove it from your project name and try again.

Answer (score 0):

Try updating your build-tools from the Android SDK manager to something newer than `19.1.0` that you are using.

Comment: thanks for the reply, i have already tried that also but no luck

Answer (score 0):

I had this bug and tracked it to the CMD processing a BAT file. After editing it worked.
the line in **tools\lib\find_java.bat** that builds the symbol **%arch_ext%** was failing; it appended a trailing space so **arch_ext** was "32 "  instead of "32".  When the symbol was expanded later, the introduced space corrupted the path.  Just add the parenthesis around the "set" operations to fix it.

```
reg Query "HKLM\Hardware\Description\System\CentralProcessor\0"   | find /i "x86"   1>NUL  && (set arch_ext=32)  || (set arch_ext=64)
```